# How do I set the correct up-stream values for all of my local branches in Git?

Tags: git, github, push, branch

I am preparing to give a hands-on coding presentation.

I have started from the `master` branch, and progressed each step on it's own branch, i.e., my branches branch off of each other and are named `Step1`, `Step2`, `Step3` and so on.

I then pushed the repository to GitHub, but when I make changes and try to push, I get:

```
PS C:\code\PhillyCCTodo> git push
fatal: The current branch Step6 has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin Step6
```

That's true for every "step".

Here is my question:  What do I need to do to be able to push to any branch, and to be able to have my students download my code properly?

The latter may already be happening, but the former is my real question.

I realize that the answer is probably in my error, but do I really have to do that command for every branch?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

Do this command

```
git push -u origin --all
```

and all the branches will be pushed up.